# setBackgroundImage doesn't work for UISegmentControl in iOS 12

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ios12

My code to customise the UISegmentControl:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "segmented_unselected_bg")
let dividerImage = UIImage(named: "segmented_separator_bg")
let backgroundImageSelected = UIImage(named: "segmented_selected_bg")

self.segment.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
self.segment.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSelected, for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)
self.segment.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSelected, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)

// to remove the seperator between segments
self.segment.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState(), rightSegmentState: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
self.segment.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: UIControlState(), barMetrics: .default)
self.segment.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: UIControlState(), rightSegmentState: UIControlState(), barMetrics: .default)
```

It works fine in iOS 10.3:

[image]

But it doesn't work in iOS 12:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: batter to set background colour according to your design

Comment: Have to use image instead of colour. This is just an example not the real image.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the image using .resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets)?

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "segmented_unselected_bg")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
```

You will of course have to adjust the insets to match your image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let items = ["Purple", "Green", "Blue"]
    let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    // Set up Frame and SegmentedControl
    let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    customSC.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX + 10, y: frame.height - 100, width: frame.width - 20, height: 48)


    // Style the Segmented Control
    customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0  // Don't let background bleed
    customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    customSC.tintColor = UIColor.white

     let myAttribute1 = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 15.0)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)]
    let myAttribute2 = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Menlo-Bold", size: 15.0)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)]

    customSC.setTitleTextAttributes(myAttribute1, for: .normal)
    customSC.setTitleTextAttributes(myAttribute2, for: .selected)
    customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    customSC.clipsToBounds = true

    customSC.setDividerImage(UIImage(), forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    customSC.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img_header"), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
    customSC.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    // Add target action method

    customSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeColor(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // Add this custom Segmented Control to our view
    self.view.addSubview(customSC)
```

Delegates method for segment click

```
@objc func changeColor(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're running in iOS 12? For me, it only shows gray rounded rectangle.

Comment: right now i'm using xcode 9.0 and i dont have ios 12 simulator in my pc so i working in ios 11 if you have ios 12 simulator  then just give it to so i can double check for you @ZhouHao

Comment: My code is working in iOS 11 too. But it's not working for iOS 12.

Comment: @ZhouHao can you share ios 12 simulator so i can add in my xcode 9.0

Comment: I think the best way to get iOS 12 Simulator is to download Xcode 10. I've fixed the issue by adding a bottom line to segment control. But apparently setBackgroundImage doesn't work for iOS 12.

Comment: @ZhouHao my machine configuration is not high so i can't update Xcode 10. so can you give me ios 12 simutor from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/  this URL

Comment: How can I pass you the file?

Comment: @ZhouHao just upload to your google drive or dropbox and share that link with me .

Comment: Send me your email. I'll email you. It's about 12MB

Comment: Sent to you the link. You need to rename it to .zip and password is 123456

Comment: @ZhouHao Thank a lots. 

Comment: @ZhouHao can you check your gmail, i sent one mail regrading ios12 ?